# DateHistogram Facet return ZERO if nothing took place at certain time

Tags: elasticsearch

I am using a date histogram to get the count per hour of some messages in elastic search. 
However the date histogram facet will only show the count per hour in the hours were some activity took place. Is there a way to force it to return zero if no activity happened during that interval.

Answer (score 1):

This is just how it works, we have some code in place on our end to populate missing "buckets" with zeros. I'm not sure yet if this is a good design decision or a bug - perhaps open an issue for it on http://github.com/elasticsearch/elasticsearch ?

Comment: exactly what i ended up doing.. I added the code on my application's end to add the zeros.